# Elasticsearch multi nested query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an elastic index with the below mapping. It has an array of vehicle and each array element contains array of info elements.

```
PUT test_nested_query
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "vehicle": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "info": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "reported_at": {
                  "type": "date"
                },
                "created_at": {
                  "type": "date"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample documents in the index

```
POST test_nested_query/_doc/1
{
  "vehicle": [
    {
      "name": "1",
      "info": [
        {
          "type": "A",
          "reported_at": 1582950792000,
          "created_at": 1582950792000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "info": [
        {
          "type": "B",
          "created_at": 1582950792000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

POST test_nested_query/_doc/2
{
  "vehicle": [
    {
      "name": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to search for documents that have `no info present at any level` OR `if info present at any level then resported_at must be present at the same level`. The query should return document

I am using Elastic Search version 6.5.0.
I am allowed to modify the mapping at the info level but not at the vehicle level.

Comment: can you tell us what have you tried ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I have tried this query.
`{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"path":"vehicle.info","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"vehicle.info"}}],"must_not":[{"exists":{"field":"reported_at"}}]}}}},{"nested":{"path":"vehicle","query":{"bool":{"must_not":[{"exists":{"field":"vehicle.info"}}]}}}}]}}}`. 
But not returning correct result.